# What is the preferred way of returning a boolean in a Python function?

Tags: python, function, boolean, comparison, boolean-expression

Is one of these preferred over the other?

## 1)

```
def even(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

## 2)

```
def even(num):
    return num % 2 == 0
```

I prefer #2, but I can see why people might like #1 too.

Comment: Not really about liking. It is due to awareness of code can be shortened to #2

Comment: I'd say it's very dependent on the complexity of the condition[s] that you're testing. For trivial/simple stuff like your example, I'd prefer #2 but it's extremely context-dependent. There's no objectively correct answer here.

Comment: Similar to [Declaring return variables in c# methods vs returning the value directly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141711/declaring-return-variables-in-c-methods-vs-returning-the-value-directly). At last, it depends on your sense of readibility.

Comment: I agree with @TomDalton, #2 is usually best in simple cases like this.

But there are cases where `if` statements are better. 90% of the time, whatever is the most readable will be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also this way:

```
def even(num):
    if num % 2 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

In general try to be consistent with the coding-style of the rest project. 
But, **explicit is better than implicit**. Imagine that during the comparison an exception occurs... Have you handled the exception on the caller? if not then you might have to handle the exception here, and then return a bool value (probably false).

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitiv answer, it's just about preference.